Show incoming call notification when the app is terminated in flutter app
I'm using Agora to implement a video call in my application, and I'm using this flutter_callkit_incoming to show incoming calls to the user.
My flow is: when a call comes, it gets a notification from FCM and shows the Flutter incoming call kit notification. The flow works absolutely fine when the app is in the foreground and in the background (not terminated from the app switcher).
When the app is terminated, FCM sends the notification for the call, but it is unable to trigger the call kit to initiate the incoming call. I need to trigger the call kit when the app is terminated.
Is there any way to do it?
Has anyone faced similar issues and solved them?
heres the FCM background Handler
This works absolutely fine when the app is in the background but not terminated, but it can't trigger the CallKit when the app is terminated.
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  

  String docName = '';
  String docImage = '';
  String uuid = '';

  dev.log('Message !also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');

  if (message.data['type'] == 'call') {
    PermissionRequestHandler.requestCameraAndMicPermissionsForCalling();
    docName = message.data['doc_name'];
    docImage = message.data['doc_image'];
    uuid = message.data['uuid'];

    logger.d('docName: $docName');
    logger.d('docImage: $docImage');

    showCallkitIncoming(docName, docImage, uuid);
  } 
 }

the function to trigger the callkit
Future<void> showCallkitIncoming(
    String docName, String docImage, String uuid) async {
    final params = CallKitParams(
        id: uuid,
        nameCaller: docName,
        appName: 'AppName',
        avatar: docImage,
        type: 0,
        textAccept: 'Accept',
        textDecline: 'Decline',
        duration: 30000,
        missedCallNotification: const NotificationParams(isShowCallback: false),
        android: const AndroidParams(
          backgroundColor: '#2E2727',
          isCustomNotification: true,
          isShowLogo: false,
          isShowFullLockedScreen: true,
          ringtonePath: 'system_ringtone_default',
        ),
        ios: const IOSParams(
          iconName: 'Getfit',
          supportsVideo: false,
          audioSessionMode: 'default',
          audioSessionActive: true,
          audioSessionPreferredSampleRate: 44100.0,
          audioSessionPreferredIOBufferDuration: 0.005,
          supportsDTMF: true,
          supportsHolding: false,
          supportsGrouping: false,
          supportsUngrouping: false,
          ringtonePath: 'system_ringtone_default',
        ));

    await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(params);
}

this is the error log when app is terminated and a call notification arrived from FCM. It didn't trigger the callkit incoming call notification rather logging this
I/flutter (21552): FlutterFire Messaging: An error occurred in your background messaging handler:
I/flutter (21552): PlatformException(java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly., Exception, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly.
I/flutter (21552):      at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.i.v(Unknown Source:12)
I/flutter (21552):      at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.i.l(Unknown Source:0)
I/flutter (21552):      at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.b.run(Unknown Source:4)
I/flutter (21552):      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
I/flutter (21552):      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
I/flutter (21552):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
I/flutter (21552): , null)


there are multiple cases in call , r u handle these? 1. if user call and receiver end call rejected, 2. if user call and immediately cancel , etc...  @Mujahihdul Islam

You're initializing Firebase like this:
await Firebase.initializeApp();

If you follow the documentation on adding Firebase to your app, it will actually look like this:
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);

Both ways of initializing Firebase are valid, but the latter code reads the value from the firebase_options.dart file from within your lib folder, while the former reads the values from the google_services.json file. So you'll have to make sure google_services.json file is up to date, either by downloading it from the Firebase console and putting it in the right place - or by (re)running flutterfire configure.

Calling FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage will invoke when notification received in background. Inside that you can write functionalities that you want to enable.
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> initPushNotification() async {

<---- other codes --->    

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_backgroundHandler); //call this and will invoke inside _backgroundHandler when notification received in background

<---- other codes --->

}


If you can, write answers with an explanation as to why your suggested code is the solution. Current and future readers tend to find that more helpful

@halfer Thanks for your suggestion edited the comment.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
